# How to skip PIDKey requirement for msi, using wix toolset?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm creating msi installer, using wix toolset. I need for user inputs, so l used UI Dialog as in documentation: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain/

In the Example shown in the link, I removed `CDKeyEdit`:

```
<Control Id="CDKeyEdit" Type="MaskedEdit" X="45" Y="159" Width="250" Height="16" Property="PIDKEY" Text="[PIDTemplate]" />
```

as it is not necessary for my application.

However, installer is showing that key is not valid during installation:

Is there any way to remove the requirement for the `PIDKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <Publish Event="ValidateProductID" Value="0">1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">ProductID</Publish>
```

Look for these and remove the first one and change the condition on the last one to empty or 1.

Shameless plug:  Check out my open source tool IsWiX.  It provides templates and designers to learn and use WiX faster.

Tutorials here:

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

To include a new custom dialog you simply uncomment one line as shown here:

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/blob/master/desktop-application/Installer/DesktopApplication/Code/UI.wxs

The code for the new dialog is shown here:

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/blob/master/desktop-application/Installer/DesktopApplication/Code/UI-CustomDialog.wxs

Answer (score 0):

> ***QA***: Please remember to test in all installation modes: **`install`**, **`uninstall`**, **`modify`**, **`repair`**, **`self-repair`**, **`patching`**, **`major upgrade`**, **`etc...`**. Hard to tell how things can conspire, no substitute for real-world testing (just to state the obvious).

---

***UserRegistrationDlg.wxs***: Limited to no testing, but here is a suggestion for **`UserRegistrationDlg.wxs`**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="UserRegistrationDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
        <Control Id="NameLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="73" Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="&amp;User Name:" />
        <Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18" Property="USERNAME" Text="{80}" />
        <Control Id="OrganizationLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="110" Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="&amp;Organization:" />
        <Control Id="OrganizationEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="122" Width="220" Height="18" Property="COMPANYNAME" Text="{80}" />
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;Back">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Next">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>Please enter your customer information</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>{\WixUI_Font_Title}Customer Information</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

---

***Quick Explanation of Changes***: There are only a few things changed.

Take out the actual controls for the CD-Key:

```
<Control Id="CDKeyLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="147" Width="50" Height="10" TabSkip="no">
    <Text>CD &amp;Key:</Text>
</Control>
<Control Id="CDKeyEdit" Type="MaskedEdit" X="45" Y="159" Width="250" Height="16" Property="PIDKEY" Text="[PIDTemplate]" />
```

and remove the associated events for the control:

```
<Publish Event="ValidateProductID" Value="0">1</Publish>
<Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
```

and finally change the **`ProductID`** condition to **`1`** for the Next button on the dialog so that a new dialog is spawned and the key is not validated:

```
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
```